# What are the rules differences in Empires in Arms?

Tags: empires-in-arms

The only version of **Empires in Arms** that I have ever seen is from 1986 by Avalon Hill.  The game was originally released by the Australian Design Group in 1983.

I've often seen comments that Avalon Hill extensively rewrote at least a few sections as well as added most of sections 10-12.

Does anyone know exactly what rules were changed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't own the Australian Design Group version of the game, and I have yet to find a copy of the rules online in any form.

The Avalon Hill version of the rules can be found in several locations. [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/5017/docs-eiarules-zip), [eia.xnetz](http://eia.xnetz.com/rules/eiarules.html) (or with [Errata integrated](http://eia.xnetz.com/rules/eiarules-with-errata.html))

This [person claims](http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/empires-in-arms/message/661) that the following were changed.

> Inf went from $2 to $3, ships from $7 to $10, guard and artillary from $6 to $7...
>
> In the ADG version, all corps were uniform, ie, all French corps were 20i3c: In the AH version The french 1st corps is 25i3c, 2-6 are 20i3c, 7-9 are 15i2c and 10-12 are 12i1c. The 4 cav corps in ADG were 7cav each, in AH they are 7 cav for 2, 5 cav for the other 2. Similar corps composition changes were made to most of the countries.
>
> Guard was added to Spain and GB, though not guard commitment.
>
> New political combinations was greatly expanded.

Without access to the ADG rules, I cannot confirm or deny these changes exist though.

Comment: These claims match my vague recollections of having played the ADG version many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

An article in Volume 24 Number 3 of the General contains an extensive review & commentary of the Avalon Hill release of Empires in Arms. The authors of the article are the designers of Empires in Arms, Harry Rowland and Greg Pinder.

Half of the article is devoted to the changes that Avalon Hill made and states that the designers are happy with almost all of them.

- Tightening of the political rules

  - limits on ceding provinces
  - alliances were strengthened
  - added the rule about not being able to sue for a separate peace when a major power is in your territory
- corp size changes
- added Tyrolian Revolt corps
- added guard infantry to Britain and Spain
- added cavalry to Russia
- extra feudal corps in Podolia, Transylvania and Crimea
- added costs to most troops
- added maintenance to depots
- added victory conditions

  - Dissolve HRE
  - garnish British trade
  - remove factors instead of corps
- VP levels were dramatically increased
- manpower added to final VP totals
- new political combinations were added
- alternate dominant powers
- restrictions on province loss by major powers
- replaced civil disorder with compulsory suing for peace.